# JavaScript Array flat function doesn't define in React native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm writing an application based on `react-native` and we know definitely we can use `JavaScript` codes in this project and all `react` projects.

But when I use below code the transpiler return *Error* to the simulator:

```
const mixer = (...arg) => arg.flat(9);
```

The error is: *flat is not function*

Why in `react-native` it is not define but in browser works well?

Comment: maybe it is not implemented in the user agent.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Thanks a lot but which user agent?

Comment: maybe where the transpiler is running ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Native uses the [JavaScriptCore](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment) engine which uses the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) spec. The spec shows clearly that [.flat](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) is not supported and it is not included in the list of transformations for babel.

Write your own or install one of the many shims available on npm.

Comment: Oh, real thanks to your clarification. I wrote my own based on `reduce` and Array `concat` function. But I wanted to know why It doesn't support, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `arr.flat` try using this function

```
function flatten(arr) {
    return Array.prototype.concat(...arr);
}

flatten(arr)
```

Comment: Actually my exact question is not a function. I said WHY. in other hand your answer is not true, because it just flat first floor of depth. I know how write it recursive and I used `reduce` function of `JavaScript` but I wanna WHY FLAT DOES NOT WORK THERE?

Comment: oh in that case, open the link below check the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283892/transpiling-array-prototype-flat-away-with-babel

Answer (score 0):

Is it supported on your platform?
[Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility)

Link also contains implementations using reduce and concat as well as non-recursive.

Comment: Please check the OP's post: _Why in browser it works well_

Comment: please check my question, the last sentence, I said why it is not defined in `react-native`?

Comment: Well it is a normal array function that is not implemented everywhere. It isnt react native at all it is plain javascript. And I gues your react native is being executed on a platform where it is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

> `const mixer = (...arg) => arg.flat(9);`
>
> The error is: *flat is not function*
>
> Why in `react-native` it is not define but in browser works well?

My first guess is that the `react-native` transpiler is not interpreting your `...arg` correctly, leading to an object that is not of `Array` type. You are trying to call `.flat`, which is a part of `Array.prototype`. Since `arg` could not be of type `Array`, it is unable to find `.flat`, thus leading to that error.

I am not certain though. Can you check the object type? You can use this code here below temporarily.

```
const mixer = (...arg) => { console.log(typeof arg); return []; }
```

What does it say? If it says `Array`, then you might operate on a platform that does not support that function yet. Using a polyfill can solve your problem here.

Comment: the `react-native` transpiler interpreted `...arg`, it can not understand what is `flat`.