# Why don't I have Array.prototype.flat available in TypeScript even though I have lib `es2019` enabled?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecma

Using typescript@3.6 and given this `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "lib": [
      "ES2019",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "cli.ts"
  ]
}
```

I assumed that I could make use of the new es2019 features while still generating valid es2018 code. So I thought I could use `Array.prototype.flat` and `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

Yet when compiling and running my code I get the error:

```
TypeError: anArray.map(...).flat is not a function
```

I am using node@10 for now and it does not natively support these functions, node@11 would but I don't want to upgrade node yet.

I was expecting to make use of future features through typescript. Yet when I look in the compiled js-file, I see the native construct being used -- so I am not wondering why it fails. I was expecting a polyfill there. I am wondering how to get es2019 features while still targeting older versions of ecma-script.

Am I enabling it wrong? What am I missing?

(This question is not about finding alternatives for the prototype functions. I am used of using lodash, that would be my fallback.)

Comment: `lib` is you informing the compiler about what libraries will be available in the runtime environment; it does not add any functionality to the runtime environment.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283892/transpiling-array-prototype-flat-away-with-babel

Comment: @jcalz You can add that as an answer. My assumption were wrong.